# Yii2 Gridview DropDownList Filter with multiple select

Tags: filter, yii2

Please help me to solve the following issue.

I have a page with data that displayed with gridview. There is a column 'status'. I need dropdown filter by this column value.

For my column in grid view I set the following filter value:

```
'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel, 'status', 
  Accounts::getStatusList(), ['class' => 'form-control', 'multiple' => true]),
```

Dropdown filter correctly display. But no matter how many options I choose, a search model gets an array with only one value .

I've tried  many ways for this but doesn't find any solution. Thanks.

Comment: Please give me your `search method code `

Comment: My filter work correctly when dropdown list not multiple - so problem not in filter.As I understand, searchmodel code must me equal in both cases. Because  Yii automaticly check $this->status (array on not array ) in where clause in serchmodel

$query->andFilterWhere([
            'status'                 => $this->status,
        ]);

So both variant automaticcly must work correctly.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. You said it fixed after run `composer update` and deleting the assets. I did the same but it didn't work. Can you please write an answer with your view code (the gridview) ? Everytime i click (holding ctrl) more than one option or select all at same time, it only search for the last one.

Comment: @bigferumdron Okay nevermind, I was running `composer update` in the wrong application haha, my bad. But I still think you should write your own answer and accept it, it helped me, ty :)

Answer (score 0):

Please read this.
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/

And code must be:

**search model**

```
/* your search attribute */
public $stats;

/* setup rules */
public function rules() {
   return [
    /* your other rules */
    [['stats'], 'safe']
   ];
}

public function search($params) {

/** some code **/

  $this->load($params);

/** some code **/

 if ($this->stats != null && count ($this->stats)>0) {
//this bad practic, but I don't find right way use " IN "
    $query->andFilterWhere( "status IN (".implode(',',$this->stats).")" );
}

}
```

**view**

```
'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel, 'stats', 
  Accounts::getStatusList(), ['class' => 'form-control', 'multiple' => true]),
```

Comment: Thanks. But this code doesn't work.  You can try it.
In searchModel params loads array with only one values

Comment: Thanks. But this code doesn't work.  You can try it.
When SearchModel load params , column status has  array with only one value. http://prntscr.com/9xzu8i screenshot.

I think problem in javascript of gridview...

PS . 
$query->andFilterWhere( "status IN (".implode(',',$this->stats).")" )  it same like $query->andFilterWhere("status" => $this->status); 
ActiveRecord automatically understand that $this->status is array, and add IN operator for that.

Comment: It works! I've done composer update, than delete all assets, and it begin works.

Comment: You can ignore the if statement if you use the andFilterWhereMethod in the following way: `$query->andFilterWhere(['in', 'status', $this->stats]);`